# C# handled exception from Dropbox is coming up as unhandled exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, dropbox-api

I have a C#/.NET app with the following code in the App.cs...

```
public App()
{
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException+=CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException;
...
}

private void CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException(object sender, System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
{
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"********************************** UNHANDLED EXCEPTION! Details: {e.Exception.ToString()}");
}
```

This has been working well. However I've been working with the Dropbox CreateFolderV2Async, and I want to catch any "folder already exists" exception, but rethrow it otherwise. My code is successfully catching this, but even though I don't rethrow it when it's that exact error, it's still showing up in my global unhandled exception catcher, and I don't know why - it should, as far as I'm concerned, be a caught error, and therefore not bubble up, but I can't see anything that I'm missing.

The code is...

```
public async Task<string> CreateFolderAsync(string Path,bool AutoRename=false)
{
CreateFolderResult result=null;
string folder=string.Empty;
try {
    result=await DxClient.Files.CreateFolderV2Async(Path,AutoRename).ConfigureAwait(false);
    folder=result.Metadata.PathDisplay;
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($"********************************** {folder} has been created\r\n");
    }
catch (Exception ex) {
    if (ex.Message.Contains("path/conflict/folder")) {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($"********************************** {Path} already exists - skipping\r\n");
        folder="already exists";
    } else {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($"********************************** Unhandled exception creating {Path}\r\n");
        throw;
        }
    }
return folder;
}
```

Being called as so (initially with the folder not existing, then of course the 2nd call it will exist)...

```
string testFolder="/TestFolder";
string createFolderResult=string.Empty;
createFolderResult=await DataService.CreateFolderAsync(testFolder);
await Task.Delay(5000);
createFolderResult=await DataService.CreateFolderAsync(testFolder);
```

And the output I get is

```
********************************** /TestFolder has been created
Exception thrown: 'Dropbox.Api.ApiException`1' in Dropbox.Api.dll
********************************** UNHANDLED EXCEPTION! Details: Dropbox.Api.ApiException`1[Dropbox.Api.Files.CreateFolderError]: path/conflict/folder/.
   at Dropbox.Api.DropboxRequestHandler.Dropbox.Api.Stone.ITransport.SendRpcRequestAsync[TRequest,TResponse,TError](TRequest request, String host, String route, String auth, IEncoder`1 requestEncoder, IDecoder`1 responseDecoder, IDecoder`1 errorDecoder); Request Id: 7f73f60a3d294c87bfe49e47ab3c3bb2
Exception thrown: 'Dropbox.Api.ApiException`1' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
********************************** UNHANDLED EXCEPTION! Details: Dropbox.Api.ApiException`1[Dropbox.Api.Files.CreateFolderError]: path/conflict/folder/.
   at Dropbox.Api.DropboxRequestHandler.Dropbox.Api.Stone.ITransport.SendRpcRequestAsync[TRequest,TResponse,TError](TRequest request, String host, String route, String auth, IEncoder`1 requestEncoder, IDecoder`1 responseDecoder, IDecoder`1 errorDecoder)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(); Request Id: 7f73f60a3d294c87bfe49e47ab3c3bb2
********************************** /TestFolder already exists - skipping
```

So you can see from the output that indeed the already existing folder exception is being caught, but even though I don't rethrow it it's bubbling up to my global unhandled exception handler (which of course is not what I want, given I **have** handled it). What am I missing here?

Thanks,
Donald.

Comment: Are you sure that the "/path/conflict/folder" string is in the `Message` property of the exception?  There are other members like `InnerException` that also contain text.

Comment: @jonsca The catch "if" statement is certainly catching it (as per the output which shows that code is executing). Are you saying it could be another exception within that? If so what would I need to do to catch that too?

Comment: Okay, but don't you want it to catch the unhandled ones first?  It seems like you're looking for that particular string "/path/conflict/folder" in the unhandled ones, and I'm wondering if it's missing those because that message is not part of ex.Message but in ex.InnerException instead.  I admit the order that the exceptions are coming back is puzzling.

Comment: What happens when you step through that method?

Comment: @jonsca No, I only want the global one to catch any exceptions that haven't been handled anywhere else. i.e. ones that I might've missed dealing with elsewhere (as best as I can tell this is the best way to do it, but open to other suggestions). I'll experiment with ex.InnerException tomorrow (it's late now where I am), but yeah, I would've thought the code I've written would've done the job.

Comment: Oh, okay, I see what you mean now.  My feeling has been it's always good to catch a specific exception type rather than just evaluate the message that comes back.  Happy hunting!

Comment: @jonsca Ah! So to expand on that a bit, I find C#/.NET not recognising the Dropbox-specific exceptions - i.e. doesn't show up in Intellisense in Visual Studio, even though the class has the relevant usings - hence the more generic approach. Also open to suggestions on how to get the Dropbox-specific exceptions recognised.

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661690/how-to-handle-error-in-dropbox-c-sharp-sdk is still relevant.

Comment: @jonsca Oh wow! That looks like it'll be applicable. Didn't come up as a suggestion when I was creating this post. You should post that as an answer, and then I'll mark it as solution if it works (again, that'll be tomorrow now).

Comment: If it works (hopefully it does!), you can just mark this question as a duplicate of that post.  This question will then serve as a signpost to the correct answer!

Comment: @jonsca Ok cool. Thank you! I can see Intellisense detecting it, so looks promising to work when I can test it out tomorrow.

Comment: Sadly none of that worked :-(

Comment: That stinks.  Sorry I could not have been of more help!